# React Native - PKPass / PassKit

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to generate Pass to Apple Wallet

https://developer.apple.com/wallet/

with React Native, but i don't found any information about it. Is it possible? I found its possible in `NODE.JS`

https://github.com/assaf/node-passbook.

I found that `PKPass` its just a compressed file with `JSON` in it and Certificates, but that doesnt help much.

But no solution for React Native. Any ideas or plugins to help me do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just finished integrating this with my React Native App, Google is your friend, there is a package for React native and there is another one for nodejs (backend) where you can generate the passes and encode it to base64, then add it into your React native app.

Here are the links:

- [Node-passbook](https://github.com/assaf/node-passbook)
- [React-Native-Pass-Kit](https://github.com/miyabi/react-native-passkit-wallet)

There are couple of gotchas, but google will give you all the answers you want, if you have problems check these points:

- Certificates.
- Add the catch on the promises to see the errors otherwise everything will be silent and you won't see any problems even if there are.
- Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, I have just a question.. Do you make the PassKit in server side or in the app side? Can you explain more about the procedure please?

Comment: @Reza server side because you need to encrypt the pass